# How to not make a loop close when giving an empty input

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my current Python project I utilize a loop via a while loop and have an input function inside of it. Thus far I've defined three different things that happen based on the use input using IF, and I've managed to use an ELSE to print a message when said input doesn't do anything.

However, when the input remains empty and is entered the loop breaks and I get an IndexError based on the *if action[0] == "go":* line. Here's the code I'm using:

```
while True:
    action = input("? ").lower().split()
        #user puts in one of the words below plus a direction
    if action[0] == "go":
        #stuff happens
    if action[0] == "get" :
        #stuff happens
    if action[0] == "exit":
        break
    else:
        print("Please try again.")
```

This code works, but as above if I just press enter or input nothing but spaces the loop breaks and I get an IndexError. How can I fix this?

Comment: place as the first `if` the following condition: `if not action: continue` (new line after the colon of course)

Comment: That's because `action = []` (an empty list) when you don't supply `input` with any input!  An empty list has no first element (`action[0]`).  You need to add someway to check whether your input is empty before accessing its elements.

Comment: Do you want the `"Please try again."` message to be printed if nothing but spaces have been entered? If you don't need the message in that situation, then just do what alfasin suggests.

Comment: BTW you should use `elif` since the cases are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

If you input nothing, `split` is giving you an empty list, so it throws an index error when you try to index it. The solution is just to check if the input is empty, and if so, skip the other conditions and continue iterating. `if action == []: break` accomplishes this task.

```
while True:
    action = input("? ").lower().split()
        #user puts in one of the words below plus a direction
    if action == []:
        continue
    if action[0] == "go":
        #stuff happens
    if action[0] == "get" :
        #stuff happens
    if action[0] == "exit":
        break
    else:
        print("Please try again.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this condition at the beginning of your loop:

```
if not action:
    print("Please try again.")
    continue
```

Comment: I know that the len(action)==0 checks to see if the length of action is 0, but one of the comments in my question mentions simply mkaing it if not action. Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: Actually there isn't any real diffrence, a list with length 0 equals NULL, and 'not NULL' equals true